# Custom directive not working inside an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I needed an circle progress indicator within cells of a table, which is rendered through an ng-repeat. So, I used an [angular plugin](https://github.com/angular-directives/angular-round-progress-directive), Which is an basically angular directive. When i use this directive within an ng-repeated div, those directive aren't compiling correctly. And, the directive is working correct, if there is no ng-repeat. 
 [Click here to view an plunker, demonstrating above issue](https://embed.plnkr.co/nEEWs8SWIqaD0VUMK4NK/)..

Comment: this is an open issue at your plugin https://github.com/angular-directives/angular-round-progress-directive/issues/2

Comment: Yea.. I know it.. But, i think we can make it work, if we modify the directive correctly, in a proper angular way.. Seems this bug is common on many custom directives.. I had faced similar bugs, while using many other custom directives..

Comment: sure. that's ambitious! I would try :)